# Curried Closures in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, currying

In swift we can define a function like this:

```
func format(name: String)(email: String) -> String {
       return "\(name)-\(email)"
}
```

I want to define a closure that is curried like that function. But compiler gives me error. Here is my curried closure looks like this:

```
let formatClosure = {(name: String)(email: String) -> String in "\(name)-\(email)"}
```

Is this simply impossible in swift or is there some other syntax for it?

Comment: Could you just use `let formatClosure = format`?

Comment: Yes I can but the problem is here defining a curried closure @connor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there concise version available to straight functions doesn't work for closures. You can still do it using a slightly expanded syntax though.

```
let formatClosure = {(name: String) -> String -> String in { email in "\(name)-\(email)" } }
```